# Use Google Workbox with manifest v3 chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, service-worker, workbox

Google Workbox sells itself as "Workbox is a library that bakes in a set of best practices and removes the boilerplate every developer writes when working with service workers."

They also state elsewhere regarding Chrome Extensions "Manifest V3 replaces background pages with service workers."

Given that, how do I use Google Workbox with the "Service Worker" replacement of background pages? Simply trying to load the background script (which works fine without workbox) in a `new Workbox("background.js")` throws a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')`. I have been unable to find a single mention of this anywhere, though it seems like a perfectly logical expectation, given the aforementioned citations.

Is my intuition correct in that they are not *really* service workers at all, and just share some of the code and user interfaces? Or have I just not been looking in the right places for documentation?

Comment: No, ManifestV3 registers the service worker internally so this library is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, I'm not sure I follow. I *want* to use the library, so in that sense it *is* necessary. Worbox doesn't just take care of registration, it also does quite a few other things, which I want to standardise on throughout my code (which is used in both a PWA and extension).

Comment: The registration of the extension's service worker is performed by the browser so this library must account for that. Currently it doesn't so it can't be used until it implements support for ManifestV3.

Comment: Also note that a service worker is used internally by ManifestV3 simply as an execution environment, so usually it has no resemblance to the usage of a service worker in a web app. What features of Workbox do you want to use?

Comment: @wOxxOm the main thing I would like to abstract is the interprocess communication, so `messageSW`. I had previously developed an abstraction layer but unfortunately with this you actually need very low level knowledge or you quickly run into edge cases that don't work. Basically I want to be able somehow to be in my client code and not care whether I'm in an ext or website env, and ideally from the SW not care who called me.

Comment: Well, since Workbox isn't compatible, you'll have to use something else. For small amounts of simple JSON-compatible data you can use chrome.runtime messaging.